# Why KeyEvent getCharacter returns a string not a character

Tags: java, events, javafx, keyevent, event-driven

Based on my understanding, the `getCharacter()` method of `KeyEvent` should return a `char` type.

For example, if I have to check if the typed key is a digit, I can just use `Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter())` not `Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))`.

I also checked the length of the returned string by printing `e.getCharacter().length()` it always returns `1`. Any explanation or other usage of this string?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--)? --- `char`s in Java are UTF-16 encoded. Unicode characters might be larger than a single UTF-16 `char`, so they "would not fit".

Comment: Actually, I am not familiar with them. Any summary? From my initial reading UTF-16 is an encoding of Unicode.

Comment: ["...  in which each character is composed of either one or two 16-bit elements."](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=unicode-utf-16)

Comment: The point is that `char`, which is a 16-bit number, is not big enough to represent all valid characters in the world. And as [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter()) states: "_The Unicode character **or sequence of characters** associated with the key typed event. Contains **multiple elements** if the key produced a single Unicode character from outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane which needs to be encoded by the corresponding surrogate pair in Java or if the key produced multiple Unicode characters itself_".

Comment: So, you mean that this string length may be 2. Do you please suggest any character that I can copy and paste in my textfield that will result in length of 2?

Comment: @OsamaEl-Ghonimy If you copy and paste it, it's not going to generate a key event (or if it does, it'll be the key stroke combination that is used to trigger the paste command, such as ctrl-V, not the text that was pasted). Try some emojis, if your keyboard has a mechanism to type them.

Comment: If you're registering an event handler for key events on a text field, you are almost certainly doing the wrong thing anyway.

Comment: Why? I am practicing converting the input length while I write. So, when I type a digit, it is converted, not when I press a button. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Another question: So, how I test if the input is digit or not. I think texting ```Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))``` will not be right in case of character of length 2

Comment: "_So, you mean that this string length may be 2. Do you please suggest any character..._" -- Example: `"".length()` will return `2`.

Comment: "_So, when I type a digit, it is converted, not when I press a button_" -- If you're trying to dynamically convert the text to a number, then that should be done via a `TextFormatter`. If you're trying to dynamically get the "length" of the text field's text, then you should do something like `aTextField.textProperty().length()`, which will return an `IntegerBinding`. For instance, you could have a label show the length of a text field's text by doing `aLabel.textProperty().bind(aTextField.textProperty().length().asString())`.

Comment: I think the problem is in my description. The input in textfield is a number representing a length in meter which I convert to cm as the user types by multiplying to 100. This is just a dummy example.
Thnaks for the letter.

Comment: is the question about `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`? From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--): "*The Unicode character or sequence of characters associated with the key typed event. Contains multiple elements if the key produced a single Unicode character from outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane which needs to be encoded by the corresponding surrogate pair in Java or if the key produced multiple Unicode characters itself.*"

Comment: *"I think the problem is in my description."*. No, it's in your implementation. If you rely on a key event handler on a text field, your application will be in an inconsistent state if, for example, the user copies and pastes text with the mouse. (And that is just one example. You won't improve the situation by also registering mouse listeners, etc.)

Comment: If you want to limit the text that can be entered (by any means) in a text field, use a `TextFormatter` as previously suggested. If you need to respond to changes that are committed, include a converter in the text formatter and register a listener with the formatter's `valueProperty`. If you want to dynamically change something *as the user enters text* (without committing the change), register a listener with the text field's `textProperty`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `KeyEvent#getCharacter()` returns `String`

> Based on my understanding, the getCharacter() method of KeyEvent should return a char type.

From where did you get that understanding? The Javadoc for [`javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent#getCharacter()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter()) says that method returns a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) object reference, not a `char` primitive.

## Avoid `char`

Understand that `char` is a legacy type, essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, a `char` is physically incapable of representing most of the 149,186 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

## Code points

Instead use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

```
int[] codePoints = myKeyEvent.getCharacter().codePoints().toArray() ;
```

You can then interrogate if any of those [code points represents a digit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(int)).

```
boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit( myCodePoint ) ;
```

## Example code

```java
String input = "A1";  // FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK  is hex 1F637, decimal 128,567.

System.out.println( "input.length(): " + input.length() ) ;  
System.out.println( "Count code points: " + input.codePoints().count() + "\n" ) ;
  
input.codePoints ( ).forEach (
        ( int codePoint ) ->
        {
            System.out.println (
                    "Code point: " + codePoint +
                            " | name: " + Character.getName ( codePoint ) +
                            " | digit: " + Character.isDigit ( codePoint ) +
                            " | = " + Character.toString ( codePoint ) +
                            "\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - "
            );
        }
);
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/FN4tgA).

```
input.length(): 4
Count code points: 3

Code point: 65 | name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A | digit: false | = A
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Code point: 49 | name: DIGIT ONE | digit: true | = 1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Code point: 128567 | name: FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK | digit: false | = 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

You said:

> I can just use Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter())

No, you cannot. The `isDigit` method takes either a legacy `char` or a modern code point `int`. The `getCharacter` method returns neither of those; that method returns a `String` as discussed above.

---

For background info, see the surprisingly entertaining article: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: This answer addresses the question well. I just want to point out that the OP never thought `KeyEvent#getCharacter()` **did** return a `char`, but rather was asking **why** it _did not_ return a `char` but rather a `String`. They did not understand, or simply did not know about, "surrogate pairs". And when they stated they could use `Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter())`, they were _wishing_ it was possible as it's nicer to not have to call `charAt(0)` (part of their justification for why it "should" return `char` instead of `String`; again, without the understanding of surrogate pairs).

Comment: @Slaw The Question explicitly, and repeatedly, says they expected a `char`. I believe it is important to stress careful reading of the Javadoc rather than programming by intuition.  Granted, they don't understand the nuances of `char` and `String` in Java, a confusing topic for any newbie.

Comment: Yes, but it's a language barrier. English is obviously (in my opinion) not their first language. The words they _used_ and what they _meant_ are different.

Comment: I think this answer is fine, in the general context of the site, because other users who have the question that is actually asked will benefit from this answer. It's probably not helpful, or even somewhat unhelpful, to the OP, because they are posting an XY problem and this will likely encourage them to go forward with the wrong solution to the actual problem they are trying to solve.